# reading a txt file with fgets and sscanf

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

I have this txt file called pedidos.txt which was printed like this:

```
fprintf(pf,"%03d%-30s%03d\n",pedido[i].nro_orden,pedido[i].desc,pedido[i].cantidad);

001Alpargatas                    050

002Zapatillas Nike               020

003Calzones                      040

004Medias levis                  025

005Chomba Adidas                 030
```

My struct is

```
int nro_orden;
char desc[30];
int cantidad;
```

I'm trying to read it in this way :

```
t_pedido pedido[5];
char string[38];

while(fgets(string,sizeof(string),pf))
{
    sscanf(string,"%03d%30s%03d",&pedido[i].nro_orden,pedido[i].desc,&pedido[i].cantidad);

}
```

the first time it reads, reads ok but the second time when it has to read "Zapatillas Nike" only reads Zapatillas (ends in the blank):

```
string = "002Zapatillas Nike",''<repeats 15 times>, "020\n"
pedido[i].nro_orden 2
pedido[i].desc "Zapatillas\000\...."
pedido[i].cantidad 19994115616
```

Any help?

Comment: how can i do to not stop at the space?

Comment: That work fine! but i have one question : %29[^0-9] it only works if the next string contains a number right? for example if the txt file has something like
001Alpargatas                    FF5, wont work right?

Comment: i see. Thanks you for the help!! much appreciated

Comment: For correctly formatted data, you won't have a newline in the 'name' string, so you could use `%29[^\n]` to look for 29 characters that aren't a newline — which allows names that contain digits (and anything except a newline).  You'd then probably want to strip strip trailing blanks.  There isn't a standard function that does that, AFAIK.

Comment: Remove zeros from `"%03d%30s%03d"`.  Use `"%3d%29[^0-9]%3d"`

Comment: Note that since you're reusing `string` there's no reason to limit it to such a small and particular size. You generally want your line buffer to be large enough to handle unexpectedly large inputs. `stdio.h` provides [`BUFSIZ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output#Constants) which is a good size to use. Also `char desc[30]` can only safely store 29 characters. The 30th is for a null byte. Instead I'd suggest using `char *desc`. Read the name into a large, reusable buffer and `pedido[i].desc = strdup(name_buf)` to copy it to exactly the right amount of memory.